# Encoding/Decoding strange issue

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, urlencode, decoding

This line of code, which decodes an encoded Chinese word:

```
URLDecoder.decode("%E4%BB%BB%E4%BD%95%E8%BD%A6%E8%BE%86%E5%BA%94",
    "UTF-8").getBytes().length
```

When I run it in a JSP page (on Jboss) it prints 5:

```
<%= URLDecoder.decode("%E4%BB%BB%E4%BD%95%E8%BD%A6%E8%BE%86%E5%BA%94", 
       "UTF-8").getBytes().length %>
```

Running it in a desktop application prints 15:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(
        "%E4%BB%BB%E4%BD%95%E8%BD%A6%E8%BE%86E5%BA%94", "UTF-8"
    ).getBytes().length);
}
```

Why? And I want the jsp to get 15 also, how?

Comment: are you SURE? carefully check if there's something else wrong. what does your entire JSP page look like? isn't the 1 from the 15 being hidden somehow? the Java code in a JSP is just normal Java code, exactly the same as Java code in a servlet (in fact, JSPs are converted to servlets).

Comment: JSP page doesn't contain any thing else the URLDecoder import statement, I use it for test only.

Comment: And no, it is 5 I see it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like JBoss is using a different default encoding, which can not represent all characters in your string. You should probably use `getBytes("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why there is a difference (that depends on the particular Java environments you're running), but I can tell you what that difference is:

There are 15 bytes in your string.  These bytes represent 5 Unicode characters, of 3 bytes each.

You can tell because the first byte of a 3-byte UTF-8 character always starts with hexidecimal "E".